# "Я думал, 10-го" или "Я думал 10-го"?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

— 14-го числа у меня будет суд.

— Я думал, 10-го.

Нужна ли запятая во втором предложении этого диалога? Как ёё объяснить?

Answer (score 9):

С запятой.

`«Я думал, 10-го»` - сокращение сложноподчинённого предложения `«Я думал, что у вас будет суд 10-го числа»`. В сложноподчинённом предложении нужна запятая.

`«Я думал 10-го»` означало бы, что говорящий думал 10-го числа (а в другие дни, возможно, не думал).